# How do I repair or replace a fascia gutter end caps?

Tags: gutters, fascia

I have a fascia gutter with no endcap at all over a window. When it rains, water pours down over the Window which seems bad...

What I'm struggling with is locating an end cap to fit the gutter. Neither Home Depot nor Lowes sell one large enough. Are they normally handmade out of sheet metal, or am I just looking in the wrong places?

[image: Missing cap]
[image: Example cap]

Comment: I've never seen gutters with that profile sold in a home store.  I would bet on needing a custom piece made, but with tin snips and the right sealant, it's probably not a big challenge.

Comment: End caps like the one shown are usually made on-site by the installer.  You should be able to get some white painted Aluminum at the home center.  Trace the outline of the gutter onto it and then extend it about 1/2" or so.  Cut like you see the existing one cut and then using pliers, bend it along the marked line.  I'd use pop rivets to attach it but you could use self-tapping sheet metal screws also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't look like a "standard" gutter shape anyways. I doubt you'd be able to buy something to fit natively anyways.

What you can try is buying some sheet metal and cutting it to size with tin snips, making fold points on the sides so you can secure it with stainless steel screws. Then you caulk it up good. It should buy you some more time until you replace the entire gutter system.